# Converting Abbreviated Date to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I have a truncated "date" attribute in the dataset, and need to convert the value below to a full DATE format (assuming it's the current year).

```
 SELECT '6-May'
```

would output:

```
 2020-05-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is very flexible about recognizing date formats. If you want to produce a `date` datatype, you can `cast` as follows:

```
select cast(mycol + '-2020' as date) mydate from mytable
```

Comment: Considering this is a string conversion, and many things can go wrong, I would only suggest try_conver() or try_cast()   Either way +1